# Blender crashing when writing python code for adding quick smoke domain

Tags: python

[image]

I am having an issue when trying to add the python code for adding smoke domain. I am not facing any issue trying to add smoke domain manually (i.e in the viewport mode), but the moment I write the code for it in python, Blender crashes. To be precise:
**bpy.ops.object.quick_smoke()**
causes my blender to crash. There isn't any complicated geometry in my scene either. Any fix for this?

P.S. I am using Blender 2.82a. The OS I am using is Windows 10 and I don't have a GPU which is compatible although I am using Eevee render engine in this case.

Comment: It would be a good idea to post your script, otherwise it's hard to identify what the cause is. Also make sure that you're not doing anything problematic that is documented on the [Gotchas](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html) page of API docs.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the same.

Comment: Looping over the material while modifying the collection looks like it will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Removing the for loop doesn't seem to help either :(